# How to show that we can always choose a smaller number?

Tags: inequality

> Suppose $A$ consists of all numbers $x \ge 0$ such that $x^2 \lt 2$. If the number $\sqrt{2}$ did not exist, there would not be a least number greater than all the numbers of $A$; for any $y > \sqrt{2}$ we chose, we could always choose a still smaller one.

I don't understand how we can choose a still smaller number than $y$.

If the number that could have been chosen is $c$, then to me this means:

$y>c>\sqrt{2}$

must be true.

But I am not sure why it must be true, because if we just select the next bigger number after $\sqrt{2}$ and call it $y$, how is it possible to select a number that is smaller than $y$ and not in $A$?

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Let $c=\frac{y+\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: Also, you're missing a bit of context; while the statement is still true as written, it's almost certain from the specific topic under discussion that the numbers being considered are meant to be (at this stage) _rational_ numbers, and that this argument shows the 'necessity' of completing the rationals to the reals.

Comment: One property that the reals and the rationals share is _density_; for any two numbers (whether real or rational) $x, y$ with $x\lt y$ there is always a $z$ (for instance, $z=\frac{x+y}{2}$ works) with $x\lt z\lt y$.

Comment: The reasoning in the grey box doesn't make sense. It first assumes $\sqrt 2$ doesn't exist, but then it uses the entity $\sqrt 2$ (which doesn't exist) in the inequality $y>\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Git Gud: I presume the second version is shorthand for 'for any $y$ with $y^2\gt 2$'.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki You're probably right. It still is an horrible thing to write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One property that real numbers and rational numbers share is *density*; for any $x, y$ with $x \lt y$, there's always a $z$ such that $x\lt z\lt y$ - just take $z=\frac{x+y}{2}$.  This explains how, if we know $\sqrt{2}$ exists, we can conclude that there are no numbers *next to* it.  But as pointed out in the comments, the argument here is somewhat circular; to run the simple density argument, we need to have a square root of $2$ in the first place.

Suppose instead that the only numbers we knew were *rational*; how could we conclude that for any number $y$ with $y^2\gt 2$, we can find a $z$ with $z\lt y$ but $z^2\gt 2$ still?  One natural approach would be to run the averaging argument on the squares of $y$ and $z$, that is to choose $z$ such that $z^2 = \frac{2+y^2}2$; but if we can't find a square root of $2$ there's no reason to believe that we can find a square root of $\frac{2+y^2}{2}$.

Instead, let's take a different tack; if we know that $y^2$ is *close to* 2, then we know that $\frac2y$ is pretty close to $y$; what's more, we know that its square $\frac4{y^2}$ is on the 'other side' of $2$; $y^2\gt 2$, so $\frac4{y^2}\lt\frac42=2$.  So let's try averaging $y$ and $\frac2y$; take $z=\frac12\left(y+\frac2y\right) = \frac{y^2+2}{2y}$.  Since $y^2\gt 2$ then $\frac2y\lt y$, so their average $z$ must be $\lt y$; but $z^2 = \frac{(y^2+2)^2}{4y^2} = \frac{y^4+4y^2+4}{4y^2}$, and so $z^2-2 = \frac{y^4-4y^2+4}{4y^2} = \frac{(y^2-2)^2}{4y^2}\gt 0$.

This construction gives us a *rational* number $z$ (that is, a number that we know 'exists') that's less than y but whose square is still greater than $2$, and this $z$ disproves y's claim to be a *least* upper bound for the set $A$ ($=\{x: x^2\lt 2\}$).

Answer (score 5):

The number $\dfrac{y^2+2}{2y}$ does the job. It is easy to check this is $\lt y$. To show that its square is greater than $2$, consider
$$\left(\frac{y^2+2}{2y}\right)^2-2.$$
Simplification shows that this is 
$$\frac{(y^2-2)^2}{4y^2}.$$

**Remarks:** $1.$ "Newton's" Method is good for things other than computing solutions of equations to high accuracy! The technique for square roots was known at least $1500$ years before Newton was conceived. A similar technique was used by Islamic mathematician/astronomers many centuries before Newton.

$2.$ There is a more number-theoretic approach, connected with the theory of continued fractions. Given an overestimate $y$, we next use
$$\frac{3y+4}{2y+3}.$$
Verification that this does the job is straightforward. There is reasonably quick convergence to $\sqrt{2}$, but not of the Newton Method level of performance.

Comment: Too bad I couldn't upvote the original and the edited version.